# How to get the rotation angle about a fixed direction when the object is rotating?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I have posted a question [How can I get horizontal rotation angle whatever device orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259193/how-can-i-get-horizontal-rotation-angle-whatever-device-orientation)

Please see the origin post to get the image of the direction of x, y and z axis.

- **pitch**: a pitch is a rotation around x-axis
- **roll**: a roll is a rotation around y-axis
- **yaw**: a yaw is a rotation around z-axis

When mobile phone is portrait, like the image showing, x-axis is horizontal and y-axis is vertical. So I can get horizontal angle by using the roll. (I can get a quaternion anytime when mobile rotating, then I can [convert the quaternion to euler angle](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/index.htm).)

But when mobile phone is landscape, x-axis is vertical and y-axis is horizontal. The roll is no more horizontal angle. So I don't know how to get is. I have tried to exchange x and y in the quaternion but no worked.

How can I get the horizontal angle? Is there a unified formula to produce the quaternion or rotation matrix?